# How to download a PDF from Vaadin Flow App?

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, vaadin-flow

How would one go about download a pdf in Vaadin? It seems it would have something to do with the anchor button, but don't know how one would go about downloading it.

I have looked at multiple resources, but none have helped. This is a prewritten pdf, not dynamically created, so that removes a bunch of questions. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945563/pdf-file-download-in-vaadin) is designed around Vaadin7, which does not help me.

Comment: If you dont want to use an `Anchor` as recommended by Erik, You can also use the `FileDownloadWrapper` add-on [here](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/file-download-wrapper), which lets you have a `Button` instead of a link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the PDF is among your public, static files, such as in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources` in a Spring app, it's as simple as this, where the file path "sample.pdf" is relative to `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources`.

```
Anchor anchor = new Anchor("sample.pdf", "Download PDF");
anchor.getElement().setAttribute("download", "downloaded-file-name.pdf");
add(anchor);
```

Otherwise, you can use this approach. In my case, the file's location is `src/main/resources/sample2.pdf`.

```
StreamResource streamResource = new StreamResource("whatever.pdf", 
    () -> getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sample2.pdf"));
Anchor anchor = new Anchor(streamResource, "Download PDF");
anchor.getElement().setAttribute("download", "downloaded-other-name.pdf");
add(anchor);
```

Note the leading slash in `/sample2.pdf`, it's important.

If we don't set the `download` attribute, the file might be opened instead of downloaded, under the name `whatever.pdf`.

If we set the `download` attribute to an empty string, it will be downloaded under the name `whatever.pdf`. Otherwise, it will be downloaded under the name we provide in the attribute.

Comment: Using this, my PDF just downloads as empty. I have saved it to resources and kept the slash at the front. Any ideas?

Comment: It might be a result of an incorrect file path, you might also get some exceptions in the logs. Note that when using the `StreamResource`, the path is relative to  `src/main/resources`, not `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources`.